# Bootstrap button outline remain highlighted after click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have the following bootstrap 4 button code.What I am finding is that only on my mobile device, the button remains highlighted after clicked. The color of it is exactly the same as if I hovered it over with a mouse on my desktop device

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary d-inline">
  Search 
  <i class="fa fa-search float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

[image: screen shot]

Or in other words, it is pretty much the same as if I clicked on the button on my desktop mouse and dont hover away.

To me, it seems like one of the following occurred

1. On the mobile device, the click on the button simulates moving the mouse to that point and trigger the click event. However, the "invisible" mouse on the mobile device never hover away??
2. Something else?

How can I get rid of this behaviour?

Comment: The #1 point you mentioned is correct. So, what problem do you want to be solved, exactly?

Comment: @ITWitch I think he wants the button style to come back after clicked (as if it had never been clicked). That may be already done on desktop but not on mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Its because mobile browsers (modern ones) support hover state.
 what you can do is override it for case of mobile with

```
button.btn:hover {
    background-color: inherit || < your color >;
}
```